# wp-login.php google CAPTCHA verification

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess

If any user accessing the wp-login.php page it should redirect to google CAPTCHA once the captcha has been solved it should show the wp-login.php page

how can i write an .htaccess rule for this ?

Comment: Why would you redirect to a CAPTCHA? The usual way to use them would be to embed them right there where you need them, in this case _on_ the login page.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to edit .htaccess file, just install a captcha login plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-recaptcha/)